# How to set up a global table of available factories by name?

Tags: rust, macros, global, factory

I am trying to build a list of available Factories to build different kind of Handlers in Rust.

```
pub trait MyHandler {
    fn handle();
}

pub trait MyFactory {
    fn build() -> Result<Box<dyn MyHandler>, dyn Error>;
}
```

I have a few concrete handler (Foo, and similar Bar and Baz...) :

```
pub struct MyFoo;

impl MyHandler for MyFoo {
    fn handle() {
        println!("Foo handler");
    }
}

impl MyFactory for MyFoo {
    fn build() -> Result<Box<dyn MyHandler>, dyn Error> {
        // Do something that may fail
        Ok(MyFoo {})
    }
}
```

Now, I would want to build a "global table of available handlers by name".

So far, i tried :

- `const NOTIFIERS: HashMap<(&str, dyn Fn() -> Result<Box<dyn MyHandler>, Box<dyn Error>)>;` which does not work, as I would then have to `.insert()` the data but a const cannot be modified.
- `const NOTIFIERS: Vec<(&str, Box<dyn Fn() -> Result<Box<dyn MyHandler>, Box<dyn Error>>>)> = vec![ ("foo", Box::new(MyFoo::build)), ("bar", Box::new(MyBar::build)), ("baz", Box::new(MyBaz::build))];` which does not compile, as allocations are not allowed in constants

I am targeting this kind of structure so I could:

- have a single source of truth to update when adding/removing handlers
- have a list of names I could easily iterate and provide in an API or CLI
- have a simple global handler factory where I could look up a handler name and invoke the build

Beyond the two attempts above,

- I though of using an enum where each type is a tuple of `(&str, closure)` which I could iterate over using the `strum` crate, but it would iterate on the enum variants (type), I would still have to setup the enum values (name and closure) from somewhere else...
- I thought I might use macros to auto-populate the list of handlers by 'simply' adding a `#[derive(RegisterHandler)` to each type of handler, but I am far too new to Rust to understand anything about macros, and even if it was generated at build-time I still would have the same 'problem' about 'storing' the resulting structure as a const of a specific type.

Right now, I am manually hardcoding the handler names twice : once to provide the list of handler types, and a second time when matching a requested handler name to call its factory. It works, but seems inelegant.

Can I build "global factory by name" and how to do it "correctly" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible, you'll just need a few adjustments.

#### Use static, not const.

A `const` variable is *copied* at the use site. This is typically not what you want. Instead, you can use a `static` variable -- of which there'll be a single instance in the program. A `static` variable still requires a const initializer.

#### Keep it simple.

You don't need a `MyFactory` trait, Rust understand function pointers just fine:

```
type Factory = fn() -> Result<Box<dyn MyHandler>, Box<dyn Error>>;
```

*Minor note: you need to box `Error`.*

#### Putting it all together.

A complete example [with playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=44db69e368d5b02a351f27fd863f7791):

```rust
use std::error::Error;

type Factory = fn() -> Result<Box<dyn MyHandler>, Box<dyn Error>>;

static FACTORIES: &[(&str, Factory)] = &[
    ("foo", create_foo),
    ("bar", create_bar),
    ("baz", create_baz),
];

pub trait MyHandler {
    fn handle(&self);
}

fn create_foo() -> Result<Box<dyn MyHandler>, Box<dyn Error>> { todo!() }
fn create_bar() -> Result<Box<dyn MyHandler>, Box<dyn Error>> { todo!() }
fn create_baz() -> Result<Box<dyn MyHandler>, Box<dyn Error>> { todo!() }

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let factory = FACTORIES
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|t| (t.0 == "foo").then_some(t.1))
        .next()
        .unwrap();
    
    factory()?;
    
    Ok(())
}
```

*Note: this is a Proof of Concept, in production, I wouldn't advise exposing `FACTORIES` publicly. Instead, I would make it private to the module, and expose a function that does the look-up and provides a nice error message on failure.*

Comment: If you use a reference to a slice, you can as well use `const` - the array itself will be `static`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: In this specific case, yes, but I'd rather demonstrate the more generic case, so that if OP (or any other reader) performs variations (like using an array) it'll be okay.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Your answer is awesome and i cannot thank you enough for it, this was driving me nuts. To recap : 1) i switched from storing an unknown-sized trait to a known-size function, and 2) i switched from dynamically building a `vec![]` which could not be compiled in as a static to defining an array slice `&[]` which can be compiled in, and finally 3) i added a public factory_by_name() protecting the static FACTORY as advised, but i changed `filter_map` to `filter().ok_or_else()?` to only get the first matching tuple, and early-returning an Err if no match was found. Cheers !